# Unable to turn off automatic memory management (AMM)

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, memory, oracle-asm

i am running oracle 11.2.0.4 SE RAC on Red Hat linux 6, the database is using ASM for datafile management

i have been experimenting with turning on AMM and set the following parameters

```
alter system set pga_aggregate_target='0' scope=spfile sid='*';
alter system set sga_target='0' scope=spfile sid='*';
alter system set memory_max_target='8G' scope=spfile sid='*';
alter system set memory_target='8G' scope=spfile sid='*';
```

but now i wanted to turn off AMM on the instances and database, but when i make the required changes

```
alter system set pga_aggregate_target=2G scope=spfile sid='*';
alter system set sga_target=6G scope=spfile sid='*';
alter system set memory_max_target=0 scope=spfile sid='*';
alter system set memory_target=0 scope=spfile sid='*';
```

i receive this error when starting the instance

```
SQL> startup pfile='?/dbs/initdev12.ora';
ORA-00843: Parameter not taking MEMORY_MAX_TARGET into account
ORA-00849: SGA_TARGET 6442450944 cannot be set to more than MEMORY_MAX_TARGET 0.
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
```

if i set the MEMORY_MAX_TARGET back to 8G i can start the database but my parameters now look like this

```
NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
lock_sga                             boolean     FALSE
pre_page_sga                         boolean     FALSE
sga_max_size                         big integer 6G
sga_target                           big integer 6G
SQL> show parameter memory

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
hi_shared_memory_address             integer     0
memory_max_target                    big integer 8208M
memory_target                        big integer 0
shared_memory_address                integer     0
SQL> show parameter pga

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
pga_aggregate_target                 big integer 2G
```

any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

cheers
dave

Comment: You stored our changes into spifile, but you use initdev12.ora to start the database. What is in this file?

Comment: the initdev12.ora file points to the spfile on the ASM disk, 

SPFILE='+DATA/dev1/spfiledev1.ora'

i am using this so i can debug the problem as the usual srvctl was not giving very useful messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case one does not want to use AMM `MEMORY_MAX_TARGET` setting has to be not set at all:

```
alter system reset memory_target;
alter system reset memory_max_target;
```

Comment: perfect, this did the job!

Answer (score 1):

Please note that you are trying to start the DB from (using the) `pfile`, where you changed values in `spfile` using commands:

1. You can edit `pfile` and set following parameters to 0

   - `memory_target`
   - `memory max target`
2. Then set following values

   - `sga_max_size`
   - `sga_target`
   - `pga_aggregate_target`
3. Shutdown all instance and bring up one by one using `pfile`
4. Create a new `spfile`: `create spfile from pfile;`
5. Start all the instances